# Behaviour of connect() for IPv4 and IPv6 addresses

Tags: c++, c

I create a socket with following params:

```
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
getaddrinfo(serverName, port, &hints, &res);
sFd = socket (res_node->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

I then make connect calls for IPv4 and Ipv6 server addresses which may or may not be present. When the server is not reachable, it has different behavior in case of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

In case of v4 it gets stuck for a very long time (some internal default timeout) before returning error. However, in case of IPv6 the behavior is changed. For some addresses the call returns error immediately e.g. address like 1111::22, whereas for some it takes longer e.g. fec0:60:69bc:94:211:25ff:fec4:6 but still lot lesser than IPv4 timeout.

Can anyone explain the difference in behavior?

Comment: Have you checked with e.g. wireshark what is going on on the wire? It might be that for ipv4 syns are dropped while for ipv6 you get back some icmp error.

Comment: The behaviour is likely to be OS-specific. It may also depend on the network topology between you and the target network.

Comment: In general, connection to localhost should succeed (or fail) immediately, remote connection can fail immediately if your host can't find a route, fail quickly but still asynchronously if an intermediate router is unable to route or a firewall blocks the connection with reset, and will just timeout if the target host is reachable but unresponsive or a firewall drops the SYN silently.

Answer (score 0):

When the route lookup to the particular target host (either protocol) yields unreachable/prohibited/reject/etc., connect() can immediately fail. Otherwise it has to send probes (ARP/NDISC, and potentially L4 packets like TCP SYN/SCTP INIT).

Route lookup example of a system without a route to global IPv6 unicast:

```
$ ip r g 2a01::1
unreachable 2a01::1 from :: dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  src fe80::224:beff:fec2:7f16  metric -1  error -101 hoplimit 255
```

Note the difference to an IPv6-connected host:

```
$ ip r g 2a01::1
2a01::1 from :: via fe80::2d0:3ff:fe93:d123 dev eth0  src 2001:527:500:770f:19e:84ff:fe9e:878  metric 0
```